# Will my class be updated if passed into anonther class?

Tags: java, class, parameters

If I were to run this:

```
private SystemData systemdata = new SystemData();
private JPanel Settings = new JPanel();
private Imports imports = new Imports();

public Main(){
    Settings = imports.setPanel(Settings, systemdata, getParent());
}
```

And in my Imports class a var in systemdata was changed would that changed the var in the systemdata class in Main?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: what is your observation in this? did you tried ? is output not satisfactory ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but there is a more important question to ask: what happens when you try it?

Comment: If you change the reference of the parameter, then no, if you can a property of the object referenced by the parameter, then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing in your class, but if you aren't doing anything complicated like making local internal copies of the SystemData object, then yes, changing it in the imports.setPanel method would affect the var from the Main method.  This has to do with the fact that objects are accessed by reference, so when you pass the reference around, the reference itself is a different variable, but the object it points to is not.

You can test it out to see for yourself, for your context.

Comment: Thanks, very informative, I didn't realise that's what parameters could do.